# Store a reactive value before it disappears

Tags: r, shiny

I am new in Shiny, so maybe my diagnostics of the problem is wrong. I am trying to create a interface that let the user create models recursively, changing it as it changes the input. In order to do that, I need to extract informations that comes from the initial training of the model and then train it again. More specifically, I want to use some specifics index and use to train it again, but every time I try to access these numbers, I get an error.

My server is like this right now:

```
    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$x12 = DT::renderDataTable(dataset[c(6,8)], server = FALSE)
  output$y12 = renderPrint(input$x12_rows_selected)
  
  index <- reactive({

      index <- input$x12_rows_selected

    return(index)
    })

  modelo <- eventReactive(input$do, {
    #Train model using indexes above
    return(modelo_svm)
  })
  pred <- eventReactive(input$do, {
    return(predict(modelo(), teste, type = 'prob')
    )})
  
  output$novos <- renderDataTable(
    dataset[which(pred()$sim > .7),c(6,8)])
  
  
  subset_data <- eventReactive(input$do, {
    dataset[which(pred()$sim <.7 & pred()$sim > .3), c(6,8)]
  })
  
  output$novos2 <- renderDataTable({
    subset_data()
  })
  

   # I want to take this "novos_index" and put it in the index() above.
  novos_index <- reactive({
    return(which(dataset$`Texto do Comentário` %in% subset_data()$`Texto do Comentário`[input$novos2_rows_selected]))
  })

 
})
```

The way I see it, I am trying to take information from something which is going to disappear when I train the model again and that is the source of the problem. Any ideas?

### EDIT

I changed the index section and added the variables that I would like to be contained:

```
index <- reactive({
    index <- input$x12_rows_selected
    if(grepl("\\d", novos_index())){ #it checks if there are numbers in the element 
    index <- append(indices, novos_index())
    }
    return(index)
    })
```

But it returns an error message saying:
"  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
Error: C stack usage  7969188 is too close to the limit"

Comment: What is the error? Please edit your question to add the exact error message and any clues you might have from debugging

Comment: I think what I really want to do is to create a variable that is updated with the index from the rows selected in the data table in such a way that new indexes are added up and the old ones are preserved.

Comment: This is a guess, but “C stack usage” sounds like you’re running out of memory. Have you tried running it locally or on a different server in a clean session?

Comment: This error probably relates to a incorrect loop I am making. There is no reason this task should be memory intensive.